# I am using the bend modifier (simple deform), as the mesh starts to bend from once end, the object which is parented at that end wont move with it

Tags: parent, surface-deform

[image]

blender image,  this is a belt and Iz want to attach the buckle while the belt bend its self simply parenting at that point wont work

Comment: Hello, did you parent to vertex? It should work, maybe share your file

Comment: Instead of using a Simple deform modifier you can spawn a circle curve and use a curve modifier with it. If you copy the same modifier on the buckle it should move when you move the belt too

Answer (score 2):

You could try parenting the buckle to a vertice instead of the whole object.

"Vertex parenting can be performed from object mode, this is done like regular object parenting, press <kbd>Ctrl-P</kbd> in object mode and select Vertex or Vertex (Triangle). The nearest vertices will be used from each object which is typically what you would want."

[(Blender Manual)](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/editors/3dview/object/properties/relations/parents.html#:%7E:text=Vertex%20parenting%20can%20be%20performed,typically%20what%20you%20would%20want.)

1. select the tag first, and then the buckle so they are both selected

[image]

2. go into Edit Mode with <kbd>Tab</kbd> and select a vertex
3. press <kbd>Ctrl-P</kbd> and it will ask you if you want to make the vertex parent

[image]

Select "OK" to this question.  Now the tag should be parented to only one part of the buckle.

Of course, you will have to rotate the tag to make the movement look more natural.

Comment: If you select 3 vertices instead of just one it will also copy the rotation of the verts to the parented object. Parenting to only one vert will only copy the location to the object.

Comment: it worked as heaven thank you so much

Comment: @Photonic great, glad it helped.  Please accept or upvote the answer if you find it useful.